# What dynamic system could these equations represent?

Tags: control, dynamics

I have equations of a dynamic system. I need to figure out what this physical system is.

The equations are:

\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1&=bx_1+kx_2+x_3\\
\dot{x}_2&=x_1\\
\dot{x}_3&=\alpha (u-x_2)-\beta x_3
\end{align}

All I can figure out is that it is maybe a mass-spring-damper system, plus a feedback control, but I am not quite sure about the terms $x_3$ and $\dot{x}_3$. What do these two terms mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it's a second order plant representing the mass-spring-damper system $P\left(s\right)=1/\left(s^2-bs -k\right)$ (stiffness $k$ and damping $b$ should be thus negative) under the closed-loop control action of the compensator $C\left(s\right)$, whose transfer function is:

$
C\left(s\right)=\frac{\alpha}{s+\beta}.
$

The negative feedback is closed over the position of the mass, while the set-point is given by $u$.

We can easily derive these results by applying the *Laplace transform* to the system of equations and then substituting $x_1$:

$$
\begin{align}
s^2x_2&=bsx_2+kx_2+x_3\\
sx_3&=\alpha (u-x_2)-\beta x_3
\end{align},
$$

from which we obtain the following transfer functions:

$$
\begin{align}
P\left(s\right)&=\frac{x_2\left(s\right)}{x_3\left(s\right)}=\frac{1}{s^2-bs-k}\\
C\left(s\right)&=\frac{x_3\left(s\right)}{u\left(s\right)-x_2\left(s\right)}=\frac{\alpha}{s+\beta}
\end{align},
$$

corresponding to the closed-loop system here below:

[image: closed-loop system]

Comment: Hi, @Ugo thanks for the reply! It makes things clear. But I am not quite sure when doing the Laplace Transform of the equations, how do you deal with the **x3** in the first equation and **x2** in third equation. Thanks!

Comment: I've extended the answer.